# Tensorflow Java API in windows

Tags: java, c, compilation, tensorflow, native

I was trying to configure Tensorflow API for java in windows.

As per the read me
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/java/README.md

It says we have to build the native library will need to be built from source for windows. But its not have detailed instructions for it.
Anyone has any luck getting it compiled?
Is there any steps I can follow?

Answer (score 3):

From the official [website](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources):

> We don't officially support building TensorFlow on Windows; however,
>   you may try to build TensorFlow on Windows if you don't mind using the
>   highly experimental Bazel on Windows or TensorFlow CMake build.

Also, a related github issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17, where one user *rongjiecomputer* mentioned (in Sep 2016):

> Tensorflow requires Bazel to build from source, If I am not mistaken,
>   Bazel is a build system like GNU Make, but not a compiler.
>
> Based on what I saw as I briefly scanned through the code, source code
>   of Tensorflow itself uses mostly standard C++ library for things like
>   threading so it should be no problem to compile on Windows, essential
>   third-party libraries it uses all have Windows support.
>
> Therefore, I think the main problem lies on lack of build method for
>   Windows rather than source code itself. There are works on using CMake
>   to build instead of Bazel but not complete yet. If someone can
>   translate Bazel build rules to CMake's, I think we will be able to
>   build it on Windows.

So I assume, if Bazel Windows works as it should, you could follow the same steps as for building it on other platforms with Bazel. I haven't tried it out my-self though.

Comment: I'd managed to install bazel in windows. Now how can I build tensorflow?

Comment: Make sure you've installed all the other dependencies that might be needed (especially CUDA if you want to use the GPU). Under Linux you would then have to run the bash script `configure` located in the top-level directory of the tensorflow sources, followed by `bazel build`. I would try it like this, but no idea if that works. This process is explained in the link I posted btw.

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/ci_build/windows/libtensorflow_cpu.sh for the script that will be used to build the release binaries for Windows in the next release of TensorFlow.

That shows how to use `bazel` (and some hacks) to generate `tensorflow_jni.dll`.

**UPDATE**: The [TensorFlow for Java maven package](https://maven-badges.herokuapp.com/maven-central/org.tensorflow/tensorflow) now supports Windows and starting with release 1.1, binaries for `tensorflow_jni.dll` are also available.